# Custom post styling per category?

Tags: posts, categories, customization

I've seen you can make custom pages with page-$name.php, but how do I do the same thing for posts?

I have two categories of posts (for example 'movies' and 'books'), I'd like them to have a different menu, background, etc..

In what direction should I be looking at?

Comment: you can create 2 page templates, read this : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use

Comment: Whatever I use: page_movies.php, page-movies.php, single-movies.php, I only get to choose it for the page template in the Dashboard. But how do I connect it with post Category type?

Comment: There it says:"To create a page template to specific post types, add a line under the template name with the post types you would like the template to support." I don't understand what this means.

Comment: Ok, solved. Why do people write this so complicated, when it's not? I've lost hours on this one.